How to get Nokia 215 into debug mode?
The code 8378#1# does not work on Nokia 215 phones with unisoc S30+. I have tried a number of codes and the closest one has been this. The reason for this question is that I would like the device to connect to my PC.
I attach the following link https://www.reddit.com/r/Nokia/comments/16jjqbo/comment/kqvdnqm/
Nokia 215 is a phone unisoc S30+
